# Cannot code jQuery UI dialog into a namespace

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, namespaces

The code shown below works fine.  I am trying to move the dialog portion (GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog line) into the GBBSO.cnst code block and I'm running into all kinds of errors - syntax, function not defined, etc.  Is this possible to do?

```
if (GBBSO == null || typeof (GBBSO) != "object") { var GBBSO = new Object(); }

GBBSO.cnst = {
    datePickerOpt1: {
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'Styles/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Select a date',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: 'true',
        changeYear: 'true',
        beforeShow: function (input) { GBBSO.dpClearButton(input); },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (yy, mm, inst) { GBBSO.dpClearButton(inst.input); }
    },

    ddlog: jQuery('<div><span><img src="Global_Template_Files/Images/loading.gif" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Communicating with the server....</span></div>')

}

GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog({ autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, width: 400, height: 100, closeOnEscape: false, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop',
    open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
});
GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog('open');
```

The code shown below does NOT work.  I receive a 'function expected' error on the open.

```
GBBSO.cnst = {
    datePickerOpt1: {
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'Styles/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Select a date',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: 'true',
        changeYear: 'true',
        beforeShow: function (input) { GBBSO.dpClearButton(input); },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (yy, mm, inst) { GBBSO.dpClearButton(inst.input); }
    },

    ddlog: {
        html: jQuery('<div><span><img src="Global_Template_Files/Images/loading.gif" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Communicating with the server....</span></div>'),
        dialog: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, width: 400, height: 100, closeOnEscape: false, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop',
            open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
        }
     }
}
GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog(GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog);
GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog('open');
```

Comment: When a jQueryUI dialog is "initialized" it is "moved" (appended) to the "body" with a new wrapper div and a few new siblings. Simply give your dialog an "ID", call upon it in that manner. If you want to associate it to a variable, `var myDlg = $("#myDlg")`. However, keep in mind, for CSS, the "namespace" will be the dialog ID, as it is moved from any previous parents.

Comment: Where exactly, in that code block there, did you establish the selector for `GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog`? At current, I see it pointing to nothing

Comment: `GBBSO.cnst` is an object. The 'dialog portion' is a function call. So what exactly does 'move into' mean in this context? It would be helpful  to show us what you have tried and what errors you have got.

Comment: Yeah I overlooked it, I see where your call is there. From what I can see, I dont see an error, and what I meant, was simply put, "if your dialog were HTML on the page in a specific element" it would be "moved" by being appended to the body. But that isn't your issue here. Honestly, We need to see the "console" errors, because I can't see a flaw in this setup

Comment: Nevermind, I see the problem!

Comment: The code shown at the top works fine, there are no errors generated.  I added one of the options I've tried to the lower code - it doesn't work.

Comment: @user652411 I removed my answer as it no longer seemed to apply, however I took you code and jsFiddled it and it seems to work just fine. [See HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/SpYk3/68hTD/)

Comment: Thanks SpYk3HH!  You added .html to the dialog assignment.  I was thinking .html and .dialog would exist on the same level - ddlog.html & ddlog.dialog.  The second example works if I use:  GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.html.dialog(GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialog);

Answer (score 0):

Second example works if the dialog function is setup correctly.  Modified the second example to fix the code and make 'dialog' less confusing.  (Thanks SpYk3HH)

```
if (GBBSO == null || typeof (GBBSO) != "object") { var GBBSO = new Object(); }

GBBSO.cnst = {
    datePickerOpt1: {
        dateFormat: 'dd-M-yy',
        showOn: 'button',
        buttonImage: 'Styles/Images/Calendar_scheduleHS.png',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        buttonText: 'Select a date',
        showButtonPanel: true,
        changeMonth: 'true',
        changeYear: 'true',
        beforeShow: function (input) { GBBSO.dpClearButton(input); },
        onChangeMonthYear: function (yy, mm, inst) { GBBSO.dpClearButton(inst.input); }
    },

    ddlog: {
        html:jQuery('<div><span><img src="Global_Template_Files/Images/loading.gif" />&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; Communicating with the server....</span></div>'),
        dialogAttrs: { autoOpen: false, resizable: false, modal: true, width: 400, height: 100, closeOnEscape: false, show: 'drop', hide: 'drop',
            open: function (event, ui) { $(".ui-dialog-titlebar-close").hide(); }
        }
    } 
}
GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.html.dialog(GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.dialogAttrs);
GBBSO.cnst.ddlog.html.dialog('open');
```